# Is it safe to overwrite LBA 2-2047

Tags: hard-drive, bootloader, advanced-format, bootsector

So back when I used WUBI before settling on using a VM, GRUB was installed (but I messed it up and had to reinstall everything (luckily I backed up)). That was back when I used Vista which starts at LBA 63. Since then, I have switched to Se7en which starts at LBA 2048. I have examined the MBR partition table and determined that on both of them.

Also, I have BOOTMGR on sector 63 on the Vista original disk, but my new disk I recently got has BOOTMGR on 2048. So my question is can I wipe this area of the disk with nulls? Yes I understand that it has to chance to go horribly wrong, but seeing the nulls on drive 2 bothers me.

Here is the MBR of the disks. The second one **isn't** a boot drive

```
HDD1: 00 01 01 00 12 FE FF FF 3F 00 00 00 3B 4C 38 01 ; Hidden boot part
      80 FE FF FF 07 FE FF FF 00 50 38 01 00 90 0A 24 ; Data
HDD2: 00 20 21 00 07 FE FF FF 00 08 00 00 00 48 38 3A ; Data + Backup
```

## LBA 2 on original disk showing unwiped GRUB data

[image: LBA 2 on HDD1]

## LBA 2047-2048 on 8 month old disk

[image: LBA 2047-2048 on HDD2]

Comment: Please clarify. You show a windows boot record on #2048 of HD2, yet say that HD2 is not a boot drive, and the fragments of partition tables you show indicate likewise.

Comment: @kreemoweet The partition is not bootable. Thats just what Windows puts in the boot sector of all NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to clear it out without issue since nothing *should* be using that anymore. However depending on your specific environment, you may end up having to reinstall the boot record, so keep your Windows disc handy to use the Recovery Options:

[image: System Recovery]

Just be careful about the range you wipe because there are parts of the file-system in those early sectors of a disk that appear empty but actually have a few bytes here and there (for example, keep an eye out for the signature `U¬` (0x55 0xaa) which can appear a few times). Be extra careful about wiping the boot-sector (2048 in your case) when setting the range.

Also, are you using HxD to do the wiping? If so, you should note that you will [not be able to do so from Windows 7](http://forum.mh-nexus.de/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=438) because as of Vista, direct/raw write-access to disks (especially to the system disk) is no longer allowed from programs without the use of a driver, which HxD does not use. You will need to either do it from another OS/live-CD or use a program that loads a driver.

Comment: Your comment about HxD is incorrect. The restrictions on raw disk writing do not apply to disk sectors outside the file system, as this question concerns.

Comment: About HxD, I thought HxD uses a libATA that communicates directly to the SATA without the OS. Also direct drive writes work with HxD on flash drives (that's all I've tested)

Comment: Unless they released a new version (alpha?) that supports it ([which they have not](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/changelog.php)), then no, [HxD does *not* support raw-disk access in Vista+ yet](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Note, they specifically says it will do so [in the future](http://forum.mh-nexus.de/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=438#p1222) and that a version that does is [not out yet](http://forum.mh-nexus.de/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=438#p1271). And yes, it does indeed apply to the *whole* disk. Just last night I tried to write NULLs to several sectors of a FAT32 disk on a separate drive and could not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless some app (such as an OEM recovery feature) is using those sectors. The same
would apply to LBA 1 (LBA's start from 0, which is the MBR of the disk).

Comment: GRUB code starts at LBA 2, so I know nothing is after the MBR